# Victimizer chastizing their victim for their feeling abused

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call someone who is mentally abusive, and shames you, when confronted about it, by sarcastically calling you a victim?

> I felt abandoned, when you didn't come back for me.
>
> "You are always such a victim, aren't you?"

Comment: From the SWR tag: "This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used."

Comment: @Cascabel Oops!

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is part of the characteristic behaviour of a *bully*.

> Bully = a blustering, mean, or predatory person who, from a perceived position of relative power, intimidates, abuses, harasses, or coerces people, especially those considered unlikely to defend themselves
>
> [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/bully)

The sneering belittlement that you describe is only one of the characteristics of bullying but is sufficient to identify the person as a bully.

In the same way we might say that a criminal may murder, kidnap, blackmail or steal, but only one of these is sufficient to identify them as criminal.

Comment: I'm not sure if we should be answering a question like this. "Bully" is obvious, and Shawna sounds like she is in a toxic relationship. I will be surprised if she comes back...

Comment: @Cascabel You may be right; I refrained from speculation about the source of the question. I thought it interesting because although the description is only part of the definition of the required word it nevertheless suffices to identify the word uniquely. That is why I gave a similar example of *criminal*. This is not such a common feature when matching words to definitions,